# Locate title in top left of grid.arrange

Tags: r, gridextra, grob

I have two plots arranged side by side with `gridExtra::grid.arrange`. I can put a title on top of them with the `top` argument. Problem is, I was requested to locate the title on the **top left** of the plot.

A reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

p1 <- qplot(1:20)
p2 <- qplot(30, 35)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow = 1, top = "Title")
```

which produces

[image]

But what I need is:

[image]

I read several times the `?arrangeGrob` file (I think there lies my answer), but haven't figured out how to achieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[patchwork](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork) is a gridExtra alternative that behaves more like ggplot than grid, including how its `plot_annotate` handles titles:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

qplot(1:20) + qplot(30, 35) + plot_annotation(title = 'Title')
```

[image]

If you want to adjust it further, its `theme` parameter accepts a ggplot `theme` call.

Answer (score 12):

Using *top* argument:

```
grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow = 1, top = grid::textGrob("Title", x = 0, hjust = 0))
```

[image]