# Align marrangGrob title to the left limit of the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

My question addresses the second solution given to this question :
[locate title in top left of grid.arrange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685458/locate-title-in-top-left-of-grid-arrange).

I would like to put the title on the top left corner of an `marrangeGrob`, but also align it vertically with the left limit of the plot.

Is there a way to do this automatically: without finding by try and error the proper value for the `x` argument of the `textGrob` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe add the title for left plot only:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

p1 <- qplot(1:20) + ggtitle("Title")
p2 <- qplot(30, 35) + ggtitle("")

grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice idea to add the title to the first plot, thanks. But do you know how could I do this using the `textgrob`?

Comment: @Reyhaneh, No. Although I can understand messing about with grobs is useful for customised plots, I by default try to avoid it.